# How to return an empty list in View in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, actionresult

I want to show all users with a specified role name. What I am doing is just specify a role name in the View. If this name exists then show all the related users (this works now), or display nothing (Exceptions arose here).
**Here is my code in controller:**

```
public ActionResult ViewUser(string roleName)
    {       
        var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        if (roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.First();
            var usersInRole = UsersContext.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(role.RoleId)).ToList();
            return View(usersInRole);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**Here is the code with a non-existing role name called "Worker" in View:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User", "ViewUser", "Home", new { @roleName="Worker"}, new { style = "color:white" })
```

The following screenshot is the result when I specify "Customer" which exists in database as the role name. If I specify another non-existing name, the result should have contained no user list.
[image]

Comment: *"Exceptions arose here"* - which kind of exceptions? Also what expected results you want to achieve?

Comment: What is the data type of `usersInRole` ?

Comment: `var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.First();` will throw an exception if no role is found with the specified name. Consider using `FirstOrDefault()` on that query instead as it will return the default value (null in your case) if nothing is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed that you're returning `User` entity instance from `usersInRole` collection inside `if` block, you can restructure `if` block to automatically return empty `List<User>` collection if no conditions are met (also added `null` checking for `FindByName()` method):

```
public ActionResult ViewUser(string roleName)
{       
    var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var usersInRole = new List<User>(); // assign instance before if conditions
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    if (roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
    {
        // change to FirstOrDefault is more recommended
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.FirstOrDefault();
        if (role != null)
        {
            usersInRole = UsersContext.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(role.RoleId)).ToList();
        }
    }

    return View(usersInRole);
}
```

Or simply returning empty list in `else` block:

```
var emptyList = new List<User>();
return View(emptyList);
```

Additionally, make sure that you're using `@model User` to bind it in view page.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what is User here? I don't have any class called User

Comment: `User` is a sample class name related with `Users` entity, the actual class name depends on what `UsersContext.Users` query returns.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i am getting you rite here .....
You want to return an empty list, that you can achieve with below :

```
private List<myClass> GetList(){
        List<myClass> list = new List<myClass>();
        list.Add(new myClass());   // Add your Class
        return list;               // retunrs a empty List
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult ViewUser(string roleName)
    {       
        var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        if (roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.First();
            var usersInRole = UsersContext.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(role.RoleId)).ToList();
            return View(usersInRole);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(new List<Users>());
        }

    }
```